# Multiple geom_smooth at differing thresholds

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot that has multiple geom_smooth(method="loess") lines for differing thresholds, but I'm having some issues.

Specifically, I want a geom_smooth() line for the all points >1 standard deviation (SD) or < -1 SD (which includes -/+2SD), one for <-2SD and >2SD, and one with all the points together. However, I'm running into an issue where it is only doing the smooth for the data within each category (i.e. greater than 1 SD but less than 2 SD.

I have made some toy data here:

```
#test data
a <- c(rnorm(10000, mean=0, sd = 1))
b <- c(rnorm(10000, mean=0, sd = 1))

test <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

test3$Thresholds <- cut(test$a, breaks = c(-Inf,-2*sd(test$a),-sd(test$a),0,sd(test$a), 2*sd(test$a), Inf),
                                 labels = c("2_SD+", "1_SD", "0_SD","0_SD", "1_SD", "2_SD+"))

plot <- ggplot(test3, aes(x=b, y=a, color=Thresholds, alpha = 0.25, legend = F)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

This creates the following plot: 
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want smoothing done for different quantities of x and y you have to manipulate the data component...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#test data
a <- c(rnorm(10000, mean=0, sd = 1))
b <- c(rnorm(10000, mean=0, sd = 1))

test <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))

test$Thresholds <- cut(test$a, breaks = c(-Inf,-2*sd(test$a),-sd(test$a),0,sd(test$a), 2*sd(test$a), Inf),
                        labels = c("2_SD+", "1_SD", "0_SD","0_SD", "1_SD", "2_SD+"))


ggplot(test, aes(x=b, y=a)) +
geom_point() +
  # just 2
  geom_smooth(data = test %>% filter(Thresholds == "2_SD+"), method="loess") + 
  # 1 and 2
  geom_smooth(data = test %>% filter(Thresholds == "1_SD" | Thresholds == "2_SD+" ),  method="loess", color = "yellow") + 
  #all
  geom_smooth(data = test,  method="loess", color = "red")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]